# onCharacteristicRead returns status 137

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

learning about BLE connection to device.

What I do is, I call

```
mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

and then it triggers `onCharacteristicRead` which returns `137`. 
As I understand that's a auth error, which means I've to provide PIN. I tried to do that using `createBond()` which triggered my broadcast receiver - there I did

```
try {
    a = (byte[]) BluetoothDevice.class.getMethod("convertPinToBytes", String.class).invoke(BluetoothDevice.class, pin);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

boolean succ = device.setPin(a);
```

So `setPin()` returns false and I'm not sure what is causing this, because I know pin is correct (string atleast. Maybe convertPinToBytes fails?).

Comment: It's hard to tell what's the problem based on the code you've provided. Please provide a minimal, reproducible example so we can see the way you set up the connection etc.

Comment: Connection setup is correct (I assume that), because I can read BatteryService just fine.

Comment: This has probably nothing to do with connection-oriented-encryption or PIN or pairing (or else you couldnt read the batteryservice). The error says you dont have the permission to read the characteristic, but depending on android version and model, this can mean a lot of things. The characteristic might not exist, or it's specified write-only, or it can only be read after encrypting the connection, or the configuration has changed and android does not know it yet..... For more help, post the detailed BTLE profile of your device.

Comment: @markus-nm Could it be possible that characteristic is encrypted and thus meaning that I do need to setPin before accessing it successfully? My guess is that 137 is an status error about encryption or something. Whenever I call createBond() it does not even open the pin dialog anymore for that specific device (other ones work).

Comment: I my recent experience with android and BLE, error 137 and error 139 both mean "generic, unspecified error". There are some characteristics which require the devices to be bonded before use (for encryption). Whether or not the device even supports bonding is up to the manufacturer, and whether this bonding requires a "PIN" or not is also completely optional. So your device might not use PINs at all. Or your client device cached all those information.